# JavaScript: значение параметра при повторном выполнении функции

Tags: javascript

По выполнении следующего кода, у нас в консоль выведется дважды `true`:

```
var booltestvar = true;

function testFunc1(){
   otherFunc(booltestvar)
}

function otherFunc(booltestvar){
  if (booltestvar === true){
    console.log("true")
    booltestvar = false;  
  }
  else {console.log("Уже не true")}
}

testFunc1();
testFunc1();
```

`otherFunc` в параметре не нуждается: `booltestvar` итак видна внутри неё, так как определена на внешнем уровне. Поэтому если мы уберём параметр из `otherFunc`, второй вывод в косоль будет `Уже не true`.

Правильно ли я понял, что значение параметра функции, если оно есть, не может быть изменено внутри самой функции и использовано при повторном вызове функции? В любом случае, прошу Вас прокомментировать результаты эксперимента.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`booltestvar` внутри функции

```
function otherFunc(booltestvar){ ... }
```

полностью перекрывает/прячет внешнюю переменную. В вашем случае, параметр передается в функцию по значению, его изменение внутри функции никак не влияет на значение переменной, которая была использована в вызове функции.

`booltestvar` внутри функции

```
function otherFunc(){ ... }
```

это внешняя переменная, любые изменения - это ее непосредственные изменения.

Называйте переменные по-разному, и будет Вам счастье.

Comment: Это когда это объекты вдруг стали передавать по значению?

Comment: @vp_arth, я не про пример, а про фразу _Параметр передается в функцию по значению_, но ведь объект, как параметр, передается в функцию по ссылке

Comment: @vp_arth, в данном контекст слово _Параметр_ выглядит как обобщенное значение, а не как конкретная сущность

Comment: @ThisMan объекты передаются по значению с самого начала. Тот факт, что объект - ссылочный тип, никак не влияет на семантику передачи параметра.

Answer (score 0):

Если вопрос в изменении значения переменной Вы можете воспользоватся тем, что любая функция в данном примере вызывается в контексте `window`. А так как `booltestvar` ноходится так же в том же контексте можно сделать так.

```js
var booltestvar = true;

function testFunc1(){
   otherFunc(booltestvar)
}

function otherFunc(booltestvar){
  if (booltestvar === true){
    console.log("true")
    this.booltestvar = false;  
  }
  else {console.log("Уже не true")}
}

testFunc1();
testFunc1();
```

Но в любом случае, все таки не называть переменные и название параметров одинаково